# openvms create file without version extension (;1,etc)

Tags: openvms

Does anybody know how can I create a text file in OpenVMS without the version extension? I need to take some logs from this server and edit them in a Linux server. Until know the downloaded file from OpenVMS server cannot be opened.

Regards,
Theodore

Comment: You don't. The ODS-5 file system always includes a version number. ([Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11).) If you reference a file without specifying a version then it will default to the latest version. OpenVMS does allow for alternate file systems, but it sounds like the problem is really on the Linux side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you google your problem? You would find answers to help you along.

As indicated you cannot get rid of the file version number on the OpenVMS side.
You can edit those file on the Linux side easily - folks do it all the time.
You indicate the file cannot be opened. What is the error message?
Best is to copy&paste the exact command used and the returned message.

On Linux You probably just need to escape the ";" with a backslash to avoid it from terminating the command fragment. Or you can put the whole name in quotes.

If you don't like that, then you may need to look at the tool used to access (Samba?), package (zip?) or transfer the file (ftp/sftp). They are likely to have a setting to honor or discard the file version.
Since you fail to indicated exactly what you are doign, we cannot help until we know.

The ZIP on my OpenVMS server has options - 
zip -h 
Info-ZIP -  Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). 
 -w   store file version numbers   -ww  store file version numbers as ".nnn"

Good luck!
Hein

Comment: Thanks, Hein, Including a backslash in front of  ";" solve my problem and now it works.